# tmux - how to bind to C-`

Tags: tmux

hello and thanks for helping a newbie.
this is my first time posting in this forum; if i posted in the wrong area or made some other newbie mistake, please let know.

tmux is fantastic.

i need to bind a key using "`" , such as C-` and M-`
i have searched and tried many ways but cannot figure it out.
i tried enclosing in single quotes, double quotes, using slashes, etc...

thanks much,
david

Comment: These keystrokes [may be captured earlier](https://askubuntu.com/q/132304/693277). Even if not, your terminal emulator or tty probably doesn't generate anything `tmux` could recognize. Do you get anything when you type (outside of `tmux`) Ctrl+v, Ctrl+backtick? or Ctrl+v, Alt+backtick?

Comment: thanks. i just learned about cat -v in the terminal. if i type alt+backtick, i get this in the terminal ^[\` but nothing using ctrl+backtick